# Bootstrap col alignment problems when in a WP loop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a custom WordPress theme using Bootstrap. When I perform the loop my resources columns get thrown in disarray as shown in the image below on the left.On the right is what I have before the loop in my static HTML template and that is how I want it to display after the loop.

[image: bootstrap_alignment_problems.png]

This is the code I have in my theme file

```
<div class="resource-row clearfix row">

  <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'DSC', 'posts_per_page' => 4 )); ?>
  <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="resource col-md-6 clearfix">
    <img style="max-height: 270px;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" >
    <h3><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>                              
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-block">Fund Project</a>                               
  </div> <!-- resource -->

 <?php endwhile; ?>                 

</div> <!-- resource-row -->
```

In my CSS file I have nothing for the `.resource-row` class and for the `.resource` class this is all I have:

```
 .resource {
   margin-bottom: 40px;
 }
```

Please help me align the `.resource` divs peacefully next to each other.

Comment: can you set max-height css property for resource  class

Comment: @Arun Thanks. Is this the only way?

Comment: May be masonry layout will help 'http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html'

Comment: Or Can you adjust execerpt content word limit

Comment: I think I will work with this. I will limit excerpt length, set a max height for post thumbnail then give .resource a height value.

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem and you accept it you should also consider voting it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the bootstrap columns are float elements. all the elements take some height as per the content inside it. so you have to set a max-height or height css for resource class.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue please set same height for all columns.

example:

.resource{

height: 100px;
}

height for all coilmn should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Set maximum height of resource class 
OR
Adjust execerpt content word limit

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit line of text to make it has the same height.

So you can add this style

```
.resource p {
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```